# POSTing a Sitefinity module with a classification to the oData web service fails

Tags: web-services, odata, sitefinity

I have a custom module in Sitefinity where one field is a Classification.

I am trying to POST a JSON object to a Sitefinity 9 web service using a route like `http://mywebsite.com/api/default/customModule`

My POST body looks something like this:

```
{
"Field1": "sample string 1",
"Field2": "sample string 2",
"Field3": "sample string 3",
"Category": [
    "6bd9a66e-0e6e-4255-b628-89b86cde6eae"
]
}
```

This is in line with the sfhelp documentation and everything works properly if I remove the "Category" field.

Currently I am getting an error of 
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Guid]' to type 'Telerik.OpenAccess.TrackedList'1[System.Guid]'`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the field is single, e.g. you are only allowed to select one category, so the request should not send an array of categories:

```
{

"Field1": "sample string 1",
"Field2": "sample string 2",
"Field3": "sample string 3",
"Category": "6bd9a66e-0e6e-4255-b628-89b86cde6eae"
}
```